# Right Join not working as expected SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am trying to use right join syntax in a real life example which unfortunately I cant show but I have demoed it as accurately as possible.

I have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Order1 
(
    PersonName varchar(10),
    Month varchar(10),
    Year1 int
);

CREATE TABLE Quote 
(
    PersonName varchar(10),
    Month varchar(10),
    Year1 int,
    Quotes int
);

INSERT INTO Order1 (PersonName, Month,Year1)
VALUES ('Fred', 'Apr', 2018);

INSERT INTO Quote (PersonName, Month, Year1, Quotes)
VALUES ('Fred', 'Apr', 2018,5),
       ('Fred', 'Jan', 2018,7),
       ('Fred', 'Feb' , 2018,23),
       ('Fred', 'Mar' , 2018,12);
```

Now I want to return all quotes regardless of whether there is an order. So I do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Order1 O
RIGHT JOIN Quote Q ON O.[Month] = Q.[Month]
                   AND O.[Year1] = Q.[Year1]
```

Which returns the exact output I would expect:

```
|   Name |  Month |  Year1 | Name | Month | Year1 | Quotes |
|--------|--------|--------|------|-------|-------|--------|
|   Fred |    Apr |   2018 | Fred |   Apr |  2018 |      5 |
| (null) | (null) | (null) | Fred |   Jan |  2018 |      7 |
| (null) | (null) | (null) | Fred |   Feb |  2018 |     23 |
| (null) | (null) | (null) | Fred |   Mar |  2018 |     12 |
```

But in my real example, I only get matches with April and no matter what join I use it is just the same result.

```
| Name | Month | Year1 | Name | Month | Year1 | Quotes |
|------|-------|-------|------|-------|-------|--------|
| Fred |   Apr |  2018 | Fred |   Apr |  2018 |      5 |
```

I guess its just bring through the matched row no matter what I do.

I thought maybe it could be something along the lines of this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Order1 O
RIGHT JOIN Quote Q ON O.[Month] = Q.[Month]
                   AND O.[Year1] = Q.[Year1]
                   AND Q.[Month] IS NULL
```

Can someone please give me some advice.

Comment: RIGHT JOIN? Well, most people find it much easier to understand `"main table" left join "optional data"`, instead of `"optional data" right join "main table"`.

Comment: The problem here, is that your sample data doesn't replicate the problem you have. This means that something in inherently different, and we can't trouble shoot something we can't replicate. You might, however, consider using a `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Comment: Do you really have a quote named "Fred?"

Comment: Do you have a where clause in your actual query? If a where clause refers to an outer joined table, it can turn the outer join into an inner join.

Comment: Show us a minimized version of the query that doesn't return what you expect.

Comment: I think you are missing the column **PersonName** in the join. Apart from this your query looks right. Your example does not replicate the real problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility...
with the data provided, you can switch the order of the tables in the FROM:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Quote O
RIGHT JOIN Order1 Q ON O.[Month] = Q.[Month]
                   AND O.[Year1] = Q.[Year1]
```

Which Produces:

```
PersonName  Month   Year1   Quotes  PersonName  Month   Year1
Fred        Apr     2018    5       Fred        Apr     2018
```

That means the tables are actually switched the other way around.